# awakeFromNib() and windowDidLoad()

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Can anyone explain what awakeFromNib(), windowDidLoad(), init() does?
I am using a class which is inherited from NSWindowController, i found the precedence as 
-init(), -awakeFromNib(), -windowDidLoad().
I want to know what these methods exactly perform.

Answer (score 3):

**`init`** is the first method that gets called. This initializes self and all the ivars, properties etc.

**`awakeFromNib`** is called after `init`. When a nib is loaded, the nib loader allocates and initializes all objects, then hooks up all of their outlets and actions. Because of the order in which this happens, you cannot access outlets in your initializer. You can try, but they will all be nil.
After all outlets and actions are connected, the nib loader sends awakeFromNib to every object in the nib. This is where you can access outlets to set up default values or do configuration in code.

**`windowDidLoad`** is a delegate method which is called when window is fully loaded. Sent after the window owned by the receiver has been loaded. The default implementation does nothing.